# Count frequency and plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I would need to plot the frequency of items by date. My csv contains three columns: one for `Date`, one for `Name & Surname` and another one for `Birthday`.
I am interested in plotting the frequency of people recorded in a date. My expected output would be:

```
         Date  Count
0   01/01/2018      9
1   01/02/2018     12
2   01/03/2018      6
3   01/04/2018      4
4   01/05/2018      5
..         ...    ...
..  02/27/2020    122
..  02/28/2020     84
```

The table above was found as follows:

```
by_date = df.groupby(df['Date']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
```

`Date` is a column in my csv file, but not `Count`. This explains the reason why I am having difficulties to draw a line plot.

How can I plot the frequency as a list of numbers/column?

Comment: your command should give the expected output.

Comment: yes, but not the plot. I am not able to plot the frequency

Comment: What's your plot command?  what did it give? And what is your expected plot?

Comment: I should expect to plot the frequency by date as in the table above (Count by date). I am just applying plot() to by_date

Comment: `by_date.plot(x='Date')` or maybe `by_date.plot.bar(x='Date')`?

Comment: I am plotting all the columns in this way

Comment: Again, `by_date.plot(x='Date')` should work just fine. You can also do `plt.plot(by_date['Date'], by_date['Count'])`. If not, check if you already `reset_index` and typos :-)

Comment: yes, there was a typo. However as you suggested the values are not matching. Am I considering the sum of all the variables in the three columns?

Comment: Maybe, there is a subtle difference between `count()` and `size`. I would do, eg. `by_date = df.groupby('Date').Birthday.count().reset_index(name='Count')`.

Comment: unfortunately it still not working. I think there is a difference between size and count, but if I use count instead of size I get an error

Comment: I also tried with `df.groupby('Date')['Birthdays'].count().reset_index(name='# of births')` but I am not able to plot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not absolutely required, you should convert the `Date` column into `Timestamp` for easier analysis in later steps:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

---

Now, to your question. To count many births there are per day, you can use `value_counts`:

```
births = df['Date'].value_counts()
```

But you don't even have to do that for plotting a histogram! Use `hist`:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
year = mdates.YearLocator()
month = mdates.MonthLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(year)

ax = df['Date'].hist()
ax.set_title('# of births')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(year)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(month)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Result (from random data):

[image: Histogram of birth]

Comment: Thank you code different. Unfortunately it does not work with `ConciseDateFormatter`. I received an error: `no attribute 'ConciseDateFormatter`

Comment: My bad. Forgot the prefix. Use `mdates.ConciseDateFormatter`

Comment: Unfortunately it has not been working also adding the prefix. I do not know if it is because of my version (it should be 3.1)

Comment: same as above. I reported the error after adding the prefix (I noticed that it was missing in your code)

Comment: Check your matplotlib version, I don't know when `ConciseDateFormatter` was added, but trying updating it to the latest version

Comment: it was 3.1. I updated it to 3.2. But it is giving me another error: `too many indices for array` due to: `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in format_ticks(self, values)
    789         # 3: hours, 4: minutes, 5: seconds, 6: microseconds
    790         for level in range(5, -1, -1):
--> 791             if len(np.unique(tickdate[:, level])) > 1:
    792                 break `

Comment: Did you convert the `Date` colum to `Timestamp`?

Comment: Yes, but there was a typo (my fault). However the number are around 8000 instead of max 150. I do not know where it gets such high numbers